# I'm having trouble using axios post in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

[image]

When I using axios post error pesistenly comes out. I also installed cors. I have no idea why this happening. Here is my react code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import axios from 'axios'

export default function Login() {

const [Email, SetEmail] = useState('')
const [Password, SetPassword] = useState('')


return (
    <div>

            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={Email} onChange={(e) => SetEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={Password} onChange={(e) => SetPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => {
                                const config = {
                                    headers: {
                
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                    }
                                }
                                const body = JSON.stringify({ Email, Password })
                                axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signin', body, config)
                                    .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
            }}>Login</button>
            <div style={{ float: "right", marginTop: "10px" }}>
                <Link to="/signup" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                    SIGN UP
                    </Link>
            </div>

    </div>
)
}
```

I'm practicing login. I didn't use form tag. Because when I submit data to backend, the console initialized and can't see what's happening. Next is my node.js code.

```
router.post(
'/signin',
[
    check('email', 'Type proper e-mail').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').not().isEmpty()
],
async (request, response) => {
    try{



        const {email, password} = request.body;
        let user = await signUpTemplateCopy.findOne({email});
        const errors = validationResult(request);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return response.status(401).json({errors: errors.array()});
        }

        if (!user){
            return response.status(401).json({ msg: "There is no user with this e-mail"});

        }

        let isPasswordMatch = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password);

        if (isPasswordMatch) {

        const payload = {
            user: {
                id : user.id
            }
        }
        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            (err, token) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.json({token});


            }
        )
        
        } else return response.status(401).json({msg: "wrong password"});
        

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.msg);
        return response.status(500).json({msg: "Server Error..."});
    }
})
```

I can't guess even what's the problem is. Please save me from this problem.

Comment: Have you tried consoling out your `errors` variable from `const errors = validationResult(request);`? Hard to tell from here, but `validationResult` probably returns something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For validating email and password I would recommend the `express-validator` library. You would implement it like so:

```
router.post(
  "/signin",
  [
    body("email").isEmail().withMessage("Email must be valid"),
    body("password")
      .trim()
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("You must supply a password"),
  ]
```

You are probably going to need an error handling middleware. The `signupTemplateCopy` seems like a confusing naming convention to what should be your `User` model, but you would take that instead and run an if conditional on it like so:

```
async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!existingUser) {
      throw new BadRequestError("Invalid Credentials");
    }
```

I use a little known npm library for that `BadRequestError()` you see above called `@dc_microurb/common@^1.0.7`. Also, instead of `bcrypt`, you may also want to give `scrypt` a try from the `crypto` library, but what you have will work.

I am also not sure about how you are generating a JWT. Let's say you were doing it as I suggest with, `const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });` or in your case, `const existingUser = await signUpTemplateCopy.findOne({ email });`, then you would take that `existingUser` or in your case `user` to generate the JWT like so:

```
const userJwt = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: existingUser.id,
        email: existingUser.email,
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY!
    );
```

Then you need to store that JWT in a session object which I do not see anywhere in your code, like so:

```
req.session = {
      jwt: userJwt,
    };
```

and then you can finally send back `res.status(200).send(user);` or in my example, `res.status(200).send(existingUser);`